# Storing in a server values sent by a client through RMI

Tags: java, rmi

Is it possible to store in a server the value sent by a client through Remote Method Invocation (RMI) process

I am doing a client that can call to a server and run the methods the last one published on the Registry.

These methods are made to create an electronic voting system. Client reach a class `IVote` to call for a method `vote(int id, int candidate)` which set a boolean variable `hasVoted` that checks if the voter has already voted to `true`.

```
public int vote(int idv, int candidat)throws RemoteException
    {
            if(!hasVoted)
            {
                hasVoted = true;
            return candidat;
            }
    }
```

I would like to create a counter on the server side that counts for the candidates remotely chosen by voters. Is it possible to do it with RMI ?

My partners told me we could only do it with TCP. I am puzzled as far as those values actually goes to a computer and are stored to process the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's possible. It's just some ordinary Java code. All RMI does is transport the arguments and return values.

Your partners are seriously misinformed.